# Oracle Recovery

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, restore, disaster-recovery

Oracle server died. Built a new VM and mapped out the volumes to the SAN. Installed the same version of Oracle on the new server and applied the same patches. How can I "register" or "attached" the oracle files > control, redo and DBF files to the new server? Oracle 10g 10.0.2.0.3. Thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your files are visible and accessible on the new server as they were on the old one, restore a pfile or an spfile (found in $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/ ) from the old server and use that to start the database.

If needed you can generate an editable pfile from the spfile to check the path's of the controlfiles. Easiest is when all path's are the same otherwise, you really need a dba to get you going.